# [Java][Hibernate] How to fetch limit of child dependency collection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate and JPA.

I have three entities `Device`, `ErrorType` and `ErrorRecord` with relation ship One-to-many (see the figure below).

Now, when I get one device, I want to get its list of errorTypes. For each errorTypes, I want to get the ONLY ONE latest errorRecord if any.

Here is my current code:

**ErrorType.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table("tbl_error_type")
class ErrorType {
    ...

    @OrderBy(value = "createAt DESC")    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "errorType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)    
    private Set<ErrorRecord> errors = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

**ErrorRecord.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table("tbl_error_record")
class ErrorRecord{
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "error_type_id")
    private ErrorType errorType;

    ...
}
```

**ErrorTypeRepository.java**

```java
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM ErrorType e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.errors WHERE e.device.id =:deviceId ORDER BY e.errorType")
List<ErrorType> findErrorTypesByDeviceIdEagerErrorRecords(@Param("robotId") UUID robotId);
```

**ErrorTypeService.java**

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<ErrorTypeDTO> findAll(UUID deviceId) {
    return errorTypeRepository.findErrorTypesByDeviceIdEagerErrorRecords(deviceId).stream().map(errorType -> {
            ErrorTypeDTO dto = new ErrorTypeDTO();
            // Some getter and setter here
            if (errorType.getErrors() != null && !errorType.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                dto.setLatestError(errorType.getErrors().get(0));
            } 
     }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
}
```

Currently, it works well with data correctly. However, because data in `ErrorRecord` increases rapidly, so there could be up to millions of `ErrorRecord` for each `ErrorType`. In that case, the performance of this API is too slow and timeout.

Expected: I want to load only one records (order by `createAt`, limit 1) in the fetched child `errors` when load all `errorType`.

I could load for all `ErrorType` first, and loop through list of errorTypes. For each errorType, make a query to get one latest errorRecords. But it seems a bad performance way, which create a lot of query to database (n+1 problem).

After researching about Hibernate query expression, I still have no idea for limit number of records in child collections.

Answer (score 1):

Getting last error record is not a simple task, as can be seen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293). Mapping such a thing using JPA mappings is impossible to my best knowledge. This is much more appropriate for a specific operation, like `findErrorTypesByDeviceIdEagerErrorRecords()`.

Also such queries are not possible to write in JPQL, only in native SQL. For instance, using [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA), it will be something like:

```java
FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((ErrorType errorType) -> {

    OrderedErrorRecord orderedRec = subQuery((ErrorRecord errorRec) -> {
        Alias<Number> rn = alias(aggregateBy(ROW_NUMBER())
                .OVER(PARTITION(BY(errorRec.getErrorType().getId()))
                .ORDER(BY(errorRec.getCreatedAt()).DESC())),
                OrderedErrorRecord::getRowNumber);

        SELECT(errorRec, rn);
        FROM(errorRec);
    });

    WITH(orderedRec);
    SELECT(errorType, orderedRec.getErrorDescription());
    FROM(errorType).LEFT_JOIN(orderedRec)
            .ON(orderedRec.getErrorType() == errorType && orderedRec.getRowNumber() == 1);
    WHERE(errorType.getDevice().getId() == deviceId);
});

return query.createQuery(em, ErrorTypeWithLastError.class).getResultList();
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
WITH q0 AS 
(SELECT t1.*,  ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY  t1.error_type_id 
 ORDER BY  t1.created_at  DESC   ) AS row_number 
FROM tbl_error_record t1 )

SELECT t0.*, q0.error_description 
FROM tbl_error_type t0  LEFT JOIN q0  ON ((q0.error_type_id = t0.id) AND (q0.row_number = 1)) 
WHERE (t0.device_id = ?1)
```

Pay attention, that I `SELECT()` additional fields, not declared in ErrorType, therefore a DTO projection required to map them. Also we need OrderedErrorRecord to hold the rowNumber. So 2 additional classes were declared:

```java
@Tuple
@Getter //lombok
public static class OrderedErrorRecord extends ErrorRecord {
    private int rowNumber;
}

@Tuple
@Getter //lombok
public static class ErrorTypeWithLastError extends ErrorType {
    @Embedded
    private ErrorContent errorContent;
}
```